# Keep having to reconfigure resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Netgear A1600 network adapter. After installing the driver for it I still couldn't connect to the internet but found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488139/installed-ubuntu-14-04-cannot-connect-to-internet-with-wired-or-wireless-conne) article saying to delete resolv.conf and create it again using your routers IP address. So then I went into my terminal and typed

```
sudo rm-f /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then recreated the file using

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

and in the document put

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

it then works until I reboot the machine which reloads the default resolv.conf and I have to go through this process again. Am I deleting the wrong file or does the OS just reset after every reboot? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will see the same behaviour if you do an `ifup` / `ifdown`.  Ubuntu populates resolv.conf [based on potentially many variables](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resolvconf.8.html) and it can be tricky to nail problems like this down.

Without knowing more about the configuration you're running it's hard to suggest anything, but check out [this answer on a similar question from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/63163).  You can override the nameserver suggested by DHCP with your target value, which should have the effect you're looking for.

This feels "hacky" and probably doesn't solve the underlying problem you're having, but it should fix your issue in the short term.

Comment: What other information would you need. Im not running a VPN and it's a great install of Ubuntu except I added vim